# MySQL replication - invalidating query cache entries (table)

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5

We lately moved to MySQL V5.5 on CentOS release 6.7 with master and 2 slaves. Since then the replication process lags a lot behind the master with the line in the process list of:

> invalidating query cache entries (table).

The global query_cache_type & size were set to 0.

I have checked around and I can see it's a known old bug in [MySQL](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60696) but could not find a workaround for this issue.

Any advice?

- query_cache_type OFF in my.cnf before server restart.
- query_cache_wlock_invalidate set to OFF.
- using default % storage_engine as InnoDB.

We ran some more tests and we had an issue with disk IO - `sar -u` showed about 3-4 %iowait, disks infra changes help reduce this to about 1.5-2% but it still doesn't help the replication not lagging for 5000(!) seconds behind the master.

Answer (score 2):

- Was `query_cache_type` `OFF` (0) in my.cnf, not merely turned off later?  (This seems to be critical for having it *really* off.)
- Another possible common thread in the bugs -- MyISAM.  If you are using MyISAM, you really should convert to InnoDB.  There are many reasons for converting.  Here are some tips on doing the conversion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb
- Make sure that `query_cache_wlock_invalidate` is `OFF`.

Comment: Well, I am stumped.  You could consider writing a bug, or commenting on one of the existing bugs.  But it might be considered just a dup.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>*Wiki answer generated from comments by [AlonP](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/85528/alonp) and [Rick James](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1876/rick-james):*</sub>

After some more tuning what helped was to update `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 0`. When value was set to 1 with `sync_binlog=1` this can cause the slave delay.

`=2` is arguably slightly better than `=0`. `=1` leads to a lot of I/O for security.  However, the slave is not the only source of the data, so a crash that corrupts stuff is not the end of the world.

`2` does an `fsync` once a second.  `0` hopes that the OS *eventually* flushes things.  `fsync` flushes pending writes to disk.